# select all text in vi to copy and past in windows

Tags: linux, vi, select

How can I select all text in `vi` so that I can copy it, and then paste it in notepad on my windows server.

I have a file with 3,000 lines in it. I cannot use FTP so I need to copy the text in the Linux environment and past it into notepad on windows.

Comment: How is the Windos and Unix machines connected?

Answer (score 2):

I'd think vi would not be the best choice with the way it handles screen redrawing. Can you run `cat filename.txt` then copy it all using cut and paste?

Just to be sure, do you connect to the server with SSH? Then you could use WinSCP from your windows machine to connect to your linux box and copy the file over SSH back. You can get WinSCP here: https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Answer (score 1):

If you can, install the `xclip` package.

First, add the `epel` repo if using Fedora, CentOS, RHEL and then install `xclip` (you can follow suit for adding any necessary repo to any other distribution you might be using:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install xclip
```

If you're using Debian, Mint, or Ubuntu, it's already in the main repos:

`apt-get install xclip`

You can then:

`xclip -i filename`

That will copy all of the text inside of the file to the clipboard and make it available to paste in Windows. I've confirmed that this works by using it to copy text via `ssh` via Mobaxterm from Centos 7 and Debian 9 into Windows.

Comment: Note for CentOS: `xclip` is not part of the base repo. To install it, do a `yum install epel-release && yum install xclip`.

Comment: True. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: This is Boeing and they do not allow me to install anything on my desktop or the server.  I can only use  the VI editor. I can only highlight about 50 lines of text and there is several thousand lines in the file. I am working on Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Can you not put in a request to your IT department to have them install it?  As highlighting everything isn't viable in this case, the best options are one of the two answers here. Certainly they'd install a simple application for you.